# Find text by search and highlight gets error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

When searching text, it finds and highlights the correct text, but other elements get cleaned such as `<p>`, `<ul>`, `<b>`, `<strong>`. All elements get removed/cleaned!

**Html**:

```
<div class="ray-search">
  <div class="field" id="ray-search-form">
    <input type="text" id="searchfor" placeholder="what are you searching for?" />
    <button type="button" id="search">Press to Find!</button>
  </div>
</div>

<article id="ray-all_text">
  <p>
    This manual and web site, all information and data and photos contained herein, are the s...
  </p>
</article>
```

**JS**:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('button#search').click(function() {
    var page = $('#ray-all_text');
    var pageText = page.text().replace("<span>", "").replace("</span>");
    var searchedText = $('#searchfor').val();
    var theRegEx = new RegExp("(" + searchedText + ")", "igm");
    var newHtml = pageText.replace(theRegEx, "<span>$1</span>");

    page.html(newHtml);
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $("#ray-all_text span").offset().top
    }, 2000);
  });
}, 1000);
```

Please check the JSFiddle example: [https://jsfiddle.net/8snb3o4h](https://jsfiddle.net/8snb3o4h/)

Why is this happening? Is there a solution?

Comment: Aariba, using `innerHTML` (`.html()` with jQuery) is evil as it will destroy events and triggers regeneration of the DOM. Avoid using it or you will encounter problem. Instead, you could use [mark.js](https://markjs.io). An example with mark.js and your use case can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/julmot/973gdh8g/)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text()` strips out all the markup.  `html()` will keep it intact.

Change:

```
var pageText = page.text().replace("<span>", "").replace("</span>");
```

to

```
var pageText = page.html().replace("<span>", "").replace("</span>");
```

---

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gaezs6s8/

`text()`

> Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched elements, including their descendants, or set the text contents of the matched elements.

`html()`

> Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element.

Comment: Great! if you don't mind can you ask a similar question? when i search it show one result in one click, i want to find same text when second click.

Comment: As in every-time i click Press to find, it highlights another one ?